# Bad Input type email, creating a text input

Tags: html

I am getting the error "Bad input type email,creating a text input".Here below are the question specifications and my code. I am not getting exactly what constraints I am missing out or going wrong.

**Question Description:**

When creating the code for your form, you must use the HTML5 tags that are appropriate to replicate the form and fulfill all the specifications listed.

Code the form with autocomplete active.

The Name field you create should have autofocus, placeholder text, and be required. Don't forget to select the appropriate type for this field as well as all the fields that follow.

The Telephone field should have placeholder text, a pattern to restrict entry, and be required. Pattern should be of the type [ Pattern: 1-234-567-8910 ]

***The Email address field should have placeholder text and allow multiple entries. This field should also be required.***

The Books field should have a data list. You can select the content you would like to list.The Quantity (Maximum 5) field should have a minimum value of 1 and a maximum value of 5.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
       h2{
           color:blue;
       } 
       h4{
           color:light blue;
           font-style:italic;
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>A Simple Form</h2>
    <h4>Form Fundamentals</h4>
    <form method="get" action="" autocomplete="on">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Customer Info</legend>
            Name: <input type="text" autofocus="on" required placeholder="Enter your name"><br>
            Telephone: <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{1}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}" placeholder="Pattern: 1-234-567-8910" required><br>
            Email address: <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" multiple="multiple"  required/>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Books</legend>
            <input list="books">
            <datalist id="books">
                <option>abc</option>
            </datalist>
            Quantity(Maximum 5):<input type="number" min="1" max="5">
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you shorten your question and explain what's the issue and what you expect?

Comment: It says there is an error at email input

Comment: specifications for email input are: The Email address field should have placeholder text and allow multiple entries. This field should also be required.

Comment: Works for me, what's wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/r29nm3fw/

Comment: That's exactly what i am not getting, this is working in my own editor but not in the one provided for our code submission... May be some constraint i am not using correctly or such thing

Comment: Editor or browser? Which browser are you testing on?

Comment: It's a console where it is displaying the error and checking for the codes submitted

Comment: It might be some extension which is throwing the errors in your console, try incognito mode.

Comment: I did.. it's the same error again

Comment: Weird, no idea why :)

Comment: Okay.. ........:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you get the error because of the forward slash (`/`) after the required in input tag of Gmail.